# Issue in plot for varying parameter value

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, visualization

I need to plot a graph of signal recovery with respect to a varying parameter k which will be chosen when the error is minimum for that k. The transmitted signal is denoted by `transmitted` and the received signal `received` is passed through a white gaussian noise and quantized by the function `Quantizer`. I calculate the distortion `error= (transmitted(channel,time) - received(channel,time))^2`. I want to plot transmitted vs distorted signal for different values of k parameter but inside the loop how do I store the values in a matrix such that I can plot and then see for which value of k the error is minimum.  In the present code, only the last iterations values are stored whereas I wanted to have a file where the recovered signal is stored along with the two channels for every k so that I may plot later. Please help how to proceed.

```
k=10;trials=5;
data=dlmread('b1.txt');
transmitted=data';
data=dlmread('b2.txt');
received=data';
[channels time] = size(transmitted)  % channels=2 time = 1024
tclass=zeros(k,time);

c=cell(k);

for iter=1:k
    [prot,class]=Quantizer(received',iter,trials); 
tclass(noprot,:)=class;
c{noprot}=prot;
recovered = prot(class',:);
    error=calculate_distortion(transmitted,recovered);

      plot(transmitted,'r');hold on;
      plot(recovered,'g');
end

function error = calculate_distortion(transmitted,received)
channels=2;time=1024;
for s=1:channels
        for t=1:time 
error= transmitted(channel,time) - received(channel,time))^2
end
end
```

Comment: There's a lot that doesn't make much sense here: `[channels time] = transmitted` is not a permitted matlab statement (unless `transmitted` is a function), `noprot` is not defined prior to use. Aside from that, conceptually you would want to proceed as follows to plot error vs. k and find the minimum: store the error for every k in the loop as shown, THEN find the minimum, THEN plot. You can store the error in an array as error(k) at every iteration, for instance.

Comment: Ok, I wanted to so [channels time]=size(transmitted) typo error, sorry. And how do I store the recovered signal at every iteration?This is what I wanted to know...

Comment: You should also be aware that there are matlab functions (although many in toolboxes) that will find the minimum of an objective function, such as an error function. However, if you can safely bracket the minimum beforehand, do not have an issue with computational expense or resolution, your manual search should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To collect the error at each iteration, you can substitute in your loop

```
error=calculate_distortion(transmitted,recovered);
```

with

```
error(iter)=calculate_distortion(transmitted,recovered);
```

Note also that you could also simply replace that line with

```
error(iter)= sum((transmitted(:) - recovered(:)).^2);
```

without need to call the function.

Then to plot you can for instance write

```
plot([1:k],error,'-o')
```

**Edit:**

The following is an example of how you might loop to collect `recovered` and `error` and then plot the best result:

```
ks = [1:k];
for iter=ks

    % ....
    % processing here .... 
    % ....
    vec = prot(class',:);
    recovered(:,:,iter) = vec;
    error(iter)= sum((transmitted(:) - vec(:)).^2);        
end

[minval imin ]=min(error);
figure, plot(ks,error,'o-k')
hold on, plot(ks(imin),error(imin),'or','MarkerFaceColor','r')

figure, hold on
plot(transmitted(1,:),'-k')
plot(recovered(1,:,imin),':g') % substitute with or add received if you like

figure, hold on
hold on, plot(transmitted(2,:),'-k')    
plot(recovered(2,:,imin),':g')
```

Note that the error computation could be taken out of the loop with some massaging.

Comment: Thank you.I had 2 queries & it is my mistake that I could not explain the second one. plot(k,error) corresponds to error for all k=10 this plot would let me visualize where the min error is.But I wanted also to plot for every iteretion, the recovered signal since the recovered signal is reconstructed in the Quantizer function. My coding is not complete but the output of Quantizer is [prot,class,recovered]=Quantizer(received',iter,trials);This recovered signal goes into the error calculation.Something like this for iter=1,k=1 : plot(time,recovered); iter=2,k=2: plot(time,recovered) & so on.

Comment: Do you want to create separate plots of the recovered signal at each iteration (which you could do for instance with subplot) or overlay in a single plot? In any case, the final plot of k vs error can be generated outside the loop after you accumulated all of the errors (although you can add points at each iteration to one plot using figure(nfig), plot(datax,datay...).

Comment: Hi,I want to create separate plots of the recovered signal at each iteration outside the loop. So, for that I need to store the values of the recovered signal after every iteration. But the values change for ever iteration. How do I do it?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to collect all of the `transmitted(:)` and `received(:)` data and then, once the loop terminates, plot the data. Please see my edit to see how you might do this.

Comment: The transmitted signal is fixed but received or the recovered is different for every iteration.The received/recovered signal goes through a reconstruction fn inside the loop & it is reconstructed with different parameters each time.Objective is to see which parameter reconstructed it best & hence the error calculation.I was thinking of storing it in something like this recovered(itr,:)=received(:) where in recovered() the second dimension stands for storing the data.I ran your code but I get the final plot from the result obtained in the last iteration.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand better now, but I am still trying to sort some things, for instance you have 2 channels (real/img?), do you want both plotted in the same fig?

Comment: Also, I imagine it is the different `recovered` you want to compare in a plot to `transmitted`?

Comment: Note also my small but important edit on how to compute the error, in case you did not catch that.

Comment: Yes, the error method is fine, i will put a tick beside the answer. And yes, I would like to plot the 2 channels which are basically 2 variables maybe separately by hold on command so as to compare with the transmitted.SO could you kindly put this as a part in your answer?Thank you for your patience and time.

Comment: Please see me edits, don't hesitate to ask more questions! (:>))

Comment: One final comment: I use `error` throughout to mean the SSE between model and data, but `error` is also an internal matlab function so it is not recommended to use the name as I have.